# Cannot Retrieve Data From mysql using php+android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Im Trying to fetching a simple data from the mysql, using JSON and php. I did everything what I googled. I can Insert the data, But i cannot Retrieve. Help me. thanks in advance.

**I have did the following php code to retrieve**

**get_all_products.php**

```
<?php

$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,pid FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();

        $product["name"] = $row["name"];

          $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];



        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**After JsonParsor, The following java code is in android**

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
ListView lv=getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the JSON data being retreived from your php code?

Comment: Im not fully aware of php concept, Basically an java developer. `array_push($response["products"], $product);` is that line pushing data to the JSOon Object? which is in the Java side that, `products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);`. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Check your logcat for the JSON Response of your code. in particular this line of code: Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

Comment: I didn't get that response. But here its coming, `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link could be very useful to the developers who are absolutely beginners.

**Arockia** Follow this tutorial. I'm sure this will definitely help.
Here it is,   check out this link:

[http://www.mybringback.com/series/android-intermediate/page/4/]

**Note:** php and MYSQL tutorial will start from number 17.

Comment: It is good. But Something is missing with me. I didn't get output.

Comment: At last it helped me, with some corrections. `header('Content-type: application/json');
require_once 'ur_db_configuration';
$query_params[]="";
$query = "Select * FROM products";
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to response it as `json` using headers, by default php will return response with `text/html`

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
```

and dont use the `mysql_*` API its deprecated, use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers), its very flexible and secure

**using PDO**

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

try {
    //connect as appropriate as above
    $db->query('SELECT name,pid FROM products'); //invalid query!
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Build your result here and response 

} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
    some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: `{"products":[{"pid":"1akn9d0uul73q0d37u1jqnkbqj","name":"Asus Phone","price":"10000","description":"Budget know","created_at":"Dec 4, 2014 9:02:08 AM","updated_at":"Dec 4, 2014 9:02:08 AM"}],"success":1}` When i run that php file, it gives this msg. but didn't get the output.. @Saqueib

Comment: I added the `header('Content-type: application/json');` content in my php code. thank you.